# transforming date and time column in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have been having the hardest time with this seemingly simple problem in R. I have a column that holds a date and a time that R does not recognize as such and I just cannot get it into a format that it will recognize both the date and the time (usually it gets the date right but leaves the time as 00:00). I have looked into the `lubridate` package, tried `as.date`, and tried `as.POSIX` but have had no luck. I need it in a datetime format that will be recognized by the `wearingMarking` function in the `physicalActivity` package. My column of dates has month, day, year, and then hour and minute:

```
dateTime <- c("7/12/2011 13:21",
       "7/12/2011 13:22",
       "7/12/2011 13:23",
       "7/12/2011 13:24",
       "7/12/2011 13:25",
       "7/12/2011 13:26",
       "7/12/2011 13:27",
       "7/12/2011 13:28",
       "7/12/2011 13:29")
```

Something like this maybe?

```
df <- transform(allData, dateTime=as.Date(allData$dateTime,format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
dfTime <- transform(df, dateTime=strptime(df$dateTime, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("7/12/2011 13:22", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`? Or with `lubridate`: `mdy_hm("7/12/2011 13:22")`

Comment: @Henrik's solution in his comment does the trick.

Comment: @Henrik, great, thank you! I knew it would be a simple answer.